# Why is Desktop bridge creating a .msixupload bundle when it used to create a .appxupload?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaf, desktop-bridge

I am using VS2017 15.9.6 with an XAF Winforms application and Desktop Bridge.
At one point I was able to create a .appxupload package to upload to the store however now I can only create a .msixupload bundle

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) dont seem to explain the difference.

I am using Create App Packages, by right clicking the Packages project.
I don't think I changed anything in the manifest.

I tried Release (Any CPU) and Release (x64)
The solution is Framework 4.7.2  I also tried 4.5.1

This [MCP Mag article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/09/microsoft-msix-replacing-msi-appx.aspx) explains that

> MSIX is Microsoft's planned replacement for the MSI and AppX formats.

However this does not help me understand why one of my projects has flipped to using it when other projects have not.

Comment: I wonder if I need SQLite.uwp

Comment: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/09/microsoft-msix-replacing-msi-appx.aspx

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/MSIX-Blog/MSIX-support-introduced-in-Insider-Build-17682/ba-p/202376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2017 15.9 added support for MSIX when targeting Windows SDK 1809 (17763) as described in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#universal3)

You should not worry about .appxupload vs. .msixupload, since the store accept both and clients running 1809 won't see any difference between one or the other.

Comment: Is there a choice? How do the packages differ?

Comment: There is no difference between APPX and MSIX. As said before it's aligned with the TargetPlatformMinVersion.

Comment: MSIX is a super-set of AppX packaging; it is starting to get more features developers are used to from the old MSI technology so the rename helps bring the concepts together.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it has to do with the minimum version of Universal Windows.
I had changed the target min version from Creators update 15063 to Windows 10 version 1809 Build 17763